# CSS file upload and store in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, html, landing-page

I would like to create a full HMTL Landing Pages within Web Studio > Cloud Pages. 
I have my HMTL code and a CSS file. 
Where do I need to store my CSS file to be able to use it when creating my HMTL landing page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within your Cloud Page collection, you can create a Code Resource:

[image: Create code resource]

After you fill out the name of the code resource, you can select the type, which in your case will be CSS:

[image]

You will now be able to paste your code into the editor, and reference the stylesheet with the url you declared during the creation wizard.

Read more about Code Resources [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_code_resource.htm&type=5).

Comment: Yup, that is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot Lukas!